# how to show *.* in FilePickerFileType (razor MAUI)

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I programmed the code line:

{ DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { "doc","jpg" } },

then the file picker show like

[image]

How to show "Alle Dateien ( * . * )" ?

Comment: try passing a `null`

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem, where exactly does the problem arise, and how do we reproduce it?